# How to create noise on a 5V PCB?

Tags: pic, adc, noise

For randomness entropy I think I need some noise. My PCB is powered with 9V battery that's reduced to 5V using 7805 and I have a PIC16F15386 on it. There is little to no noise on the power lines so I cannot use that. My book on analog electronics says that zener diodes produces some noise, especially above 6V.

Question 1: Would it be possible to add a 7.5V zener to the board and use the PIC A/D to read the zener, and use the result as a start value for srand()? Or will that not be enough?

Question 2: The PIC uses INTOSC and I have the ability to use the clock out-pin. Can I feed the clock signal to the A/D and use that as a noise generator?

Are there any other ways I can explore?

**EDIT:** Added name of PIC.

Comment: Which PIC micro? Some might include a random number generator already. If not, are there any other inputs? Uninitialized memory? IO pins with random timings like pushbuttons, or different speed oscillators you can read, built in voltage references, etc? EEPROM memory you can read at boot and store which seed to use at next boot?

Comment: Are you sure the implementation of srand provides the entropy you need? You may be focusing on the wrong part here. If you want something cryptographically secure, you should use proper libraries/hardware.

Comment: https://www.lavalamp.com/lava-lamps-encryption/

Comment: @RonBeyer: Cryptographically secure entropy is way above fancyness for this hack.

Comment: @Justme: The only human interfaceable randomness in this project is a power switch, which unfortunately will not help me here.

Comment: Zener would produce mV level noise, you might need 40-60dB gain into an ADC to get useful entropy.

Comment: @BrianDrummond: I have plenty of board space left. What if I add an LM358 and use that to amplify the zener noise for ADC?

Comment: 358 is a pretty poor opamp; offhand, 2 of them with 20-30dB gain each may work.

Answer (score 1):

Question 2: it looks like the clock you’re proposing to use is the same clock that drives the ADC itself, so that would not work.  Even if it were an independent clock it would be a poor random number generator since the ratio of the clock to the ADC conversions would produce patterns in the numbers that you generate